# Material Design layout animation

Tags: android, animation, material-design

One of the ideas of Android L is that popup window need to start their apparition from the point where the user tapped the screen.
For example, in Chrome Beta (@time * 5) :
[image: Chrome Beta]

The idea is to be able to make the view grow from any pivot point (not just the predetermined position of the overflow button)
Has anybody been able to do this or is not doable at the moment ?

Comment: You want to apply this animation on listview items? or just on a simple view?

Comment: Posting a video of _exactly_ what you want will definitely help. `adb shell screenrecord`?

Comment: @Vikram good idea, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it there is no clean way to do this.
The only viable option I have found is to write 4 different xml animations (for the 4 corners, more if you want to allow for centered growing), all ScaleAnimations from 0 to 1, with different pivot points for each (the 4 corners).

Then, use a `DialogFragment` :

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = 
         R.style.downRightCornerAnimation;
    //instead of referring to R.*, call a method to get the specific
    //resource you need for a given start position
    return dialog;
}
```

And one example of such an animation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
       android:fromXScale="0.0"
       android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="0.0"
       android:toYScale="1.0"
       android:fillAfter="false"
       android:duration="200" 
       android:pivotX = "0%"
       android:pivotY = "100%"/>
```

It is very unwieldy and hacky but I don't think the SDK gives us a better tool to do this (AFAIK you can't just inject a dynamic `ObjectAnimator` in `DialogFragment` or `PopupWindow`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess doing an animation in a general View should work for you.

In order to do that, implement the following code:

```
RecyclerView view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.your_view);
Animation appear = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.appear);
apear.startAnimation(view);
```

Then, inside your res/anim folder (create it if isn't there), create a xml file named appear.xml and put the following code:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:android:fromXScale="0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

Change the values for what fit your purposes.

You can get more information in the android developers [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) reference and [View Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) API guide.